# Cast error (Type constraint missmatch)

Tags: f#

I have problem with casting

```
    type IConfig = interface end

    type test(num: string) = 
        interface IConfig
        member this.num = num


    type init(context:string) = 
        interface IConfig
        member this.context = context


let dict:Dictionary<string, IConfig> = new Dictionary<string, IConfig>()
dict.Add("x1", new test() { num = "1" });
dict.Add("x2", new init() { context = "1" });

for item in dict do
    if(item.Key = "x1") then
        let x = (item.Value :> init).context 
//Here I have an error: Type constraint missmach. The type IConfig is not compatibile with type InitConfig
```

I've done the same with C#, and it works.
Please, help.

Comment: Could you please provide the exact code that produce the error because the one you provide is bogus in many ways: missing open statements, bogus use of the test and init constructors…). My editors reports other errors than the one you are talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to make some changes to your code to get it working, but I think you're looking for the `:?>` operator instead of the `:>` operator.  The `:>` only does upcasting (i.e. `init -> IConfig`), whereas `:?>` does downcasting (i.e. `IConfig -> init`), which is what you're trying to do here.

Here's the code I used to get it working:

```
open System.Collections.Generic

type IConfig = interface end

type test(num: string) = 
    interface IConfig
    member this.num = num


type init(context:string) = 
    interface IConfig
    member this.context = context


let dict:Dictionary<string, IConfig> = new Dictionary<string, IConfig>()
dict.Add("x1", new test(num = "1"))
dict.Add("x2", new init(context = "1"))

for item in dict do
    if(item.Key = "x2") then
        let x = (item.Value :?> init).context 
        printfn "%A" x
```

Comment: Talking about changes, I would have used the [dict operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/extratopleveloperators.dict%5B'key,'value%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) to create the dictionary.

Comment: @Thomas Corbière, Certainly, there are many changes I would suggest if I were doing a code review of this question.  I attempted to keep the code as close to the original as possible while still fixing the compiler errors and the runtime behavior.